# ValueError: signal only works in main thread while implementing Scrapy in Streamlit

Tags: python, multithreading, scrapy, signals, streamlit

This error occurs when I try to implement scrapy in streamlit. Scrapy uses signals and it only works on the main thread whereas when running this command in my streamlit code `st.text(threading.current_thread().name)` it is known that streamlit runs on ScriptRunner.scriptThread therefore signals are not working on this thread

**How am I calling scrapy**:
I defined a function in the amazon.py file where my class is defined, function is as follows

```
def run_prog(baseUrl,s_date,e_date,min_l,max_l):
    if "twisted.internet.reactor" in sys.modules:
        del sys.modules["twisted.internet.reactor"]

    print(threading.current_thread().name)
    cmdline.execute(f'scrapy crawl amazonreviews -a parameters={{"baseUrl":"{baseUrl}","start_date":"{s_date}","end_date":"{e_date}","min_l":"{min_l}","max_l":"{max_l}"}} -O amzn.json'.split())
```

I am using cmdline.execute to run the scrapy, this function is later called in my streamlit code by importing this function like this

```
config= json.loads(st.session_state['json_obj'])
        s_date=config['start_datetime']
        e_date=config['end_datetime']
        min_l=config['min_comment_len']
        max_l=config['max_comment_len']
        links=config['url_input']
        for link in links:
            run_prog(link,s_date,e_date,min_l,max_l)
```

The issue is when I run the amazon.py file standalone like a python file it works but when I implement it on streamlit and run via a function call it doesn't work and throws me a signal error as the signal only works in the main thread and streamlit runs on a different thread.
I looked it up on StackOverflow and there are methods that say using `CrawlerRunner`solves it but I think this is more of an issue of signals and them not working in other threads.

**So is there any way of streamlit running on the main thread or disabling signaling in scrapy** while using `cmdline.execute` to execute the code instead of `CrawlerProcess` or `CrawlerRunner`because one can easily pass user inputs via cmdline.execute

Specs:
Python-3.7.9,
Streamlit-1.10.0,
Scrapy-2.6.1